# Ala-El-Din Muhammed El Ferjumedhi

Tags: algebra, islamic-science

I'm looking for more details of a 14th century mathematician Ala-El-Din Muhammad El Ferjumedhi.

I'm translating a popular book on the history of mathematics, and there is one figure that shows a mathematical manuscript in Arabic. I could find it on [Getty Images](https://www.gettyimages.de/detail/nachrichtenfoto/treatise-on-the-question-of-arithmetic-code-by-the-nachrichtenfoto/142086185), where it carries the description "SAUDI ARABIA - CIRCA 2002: Treatise on the Question of Arithmetic Code by The Master Ala-El-Din Muhammed El Ferjumedhi, Saudi Arabia, 14th Century.", but I cannot find this mathematician anywhere, even when I search for different possible spellings of his name.

[image: Treatise on the Question of Arithmetic Code]

Any more information about this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just search the last name Ferjumedhi in Google books. I could find couple of other books from 1840s  but those are in Swedish, It does seem to have paragraphs on this mathematician and the name of his book is mentioned. I cannot understand the rest. https://books.google.com/books?id=cx1OAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA221&dq=Ferjumedhi&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiirf7ul5TlAhUDXK0KHS17BZEQ6AEwAnoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=Ferjumedhi&f=false

Comment: Since the book you are translating is quite recent, the authors can be contacted and ask them where did they get this image. Seems like a secondary source because would have mentioned more details.

Comment: The book linked by @M.Farooq is in Latin. My Latin is extremely rusty, but it seems to say that the Treatise on Questions of Arithmetic mentioned in the question was finished in the year 712 (Islamic calendar, roughly corresponding to A.D. 1312), and that the book is in two parts, of which the first covers multiplication and division, and the second geodesic computations. It contains an introduction which explains necessary technical terms.

Comment: I am not sure where "Code" in the translation of the book's title is coming from, because in the Swedish source the Latin title is given as *Tractatus Alaiticus de questionibus arithmeticis*, where *Alaiticus* seems to be a reference to a person "Alayi"?

Comment: @M.Farooq Contacting the authors of my book is difficult as it's a collaborative work and I would have to go through a long chain of publishers to even find out who contributed this particular bit. In any case, the image is from Getty Images (link) and the authors just copied essentially the same info as the Getty page, so likely don't know more.

Comment: @M.Farooq Thanks for finding the book on google books - that is very helpful and something I can follow up!

Comment: @njuffa Based on how other Arabic books were translated into Latin, I would say the Alaiticus is the latinised form of Ala-Ed-Din, so it would mean "The treatise of Ala-Ed-Din about arithmetic questions". They didn't always translate the original Arabic title literally but gave it a title like "The book of the famous [Name] about [topic]"; I think it sold better in the Latin world when you mentioned the Arabic name as they were highly regarded as scientific authorities.

Comment: @njuffa I think the book from 1849 (which is some kind of thesis by Carl Johan Tornberg at Uppsala university) refers to a different manuscript. My understanding of the Latin (which is also rusty) is that the "Treatise of Alaiticus" was written by Sa'ad el-Soghdi (called Djemal the Turk) for his teacher Ala-Ed-Din el-Ferjumedhi. The Getty Images description seems to imply that their manuscript was discovered around 2002 in Saudi Arabia, so presumably not know to Tornberg.

Comment: I think you should convert your comments into a self-answer. It is unlikely that much more information on Ferjumedhi is available. He seems to be an obscure scholar, and the Getty treatise is just expository, with no original material.

Comment: The usual English transcription of his name is (al-)Faryumadhi الفريومذى. He is mentioned in the standard Arabist sources like Brockelmann.